# How to choose the name for an X.509 company certificate?

Tags: certificate, code-signing, x509certificate, naming, x509

I'd like to create a certificate to sign our company's software. The tool that I'm using for this ([keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) from the Java SDK) expects the distinguished name in the following format:

```
CN=commonName, OU=organizationalUnit, O=organizationName, L=city, S=state, C=countryCode
```

If I just want a certificate for my company (not for any particular person therein), should I use

```
CN=MyCompany, C=AT
```

or

```
O=MyCompany, C=AT
```

as the distinguished name? The latter would make more sense (since MyCompany is the name of the organization), but I don't know if it's "correct" to leave the commonName empty.

Comment: It is common practice to put your FQDN in the CN.

Comment: @Stefan this is only so for certificates, used in SSL/TLS (and even there the CN can be empty and the domain name can be placed in SubjectAlternativeName extension). For code signing this makes no sense.

Comment: "It is common practice to put your FQDN in the CN" - that practice is deprecated in the [CA/B Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) (see Section 9). The names should always be in the `SAN` (and if a `CN` is present, it must also be listed in a `SAN`). I don't believe the RFCs (2818, 5280, 6125) have a similar restriction (but they are fast and loose anyways). However I get the impression @Heinzi is *not* talking about end entity certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CommonName can hold your company name as well. Or you can leave it empty - this doesn't matter as the standard has no requirement on the number of elements in SubjectName, neither there's a standard for CommonName format.

However, your whole task doesn't seem to make much sense. You are going to create a self-signed certificate for signing your software, but no validator would accept such signature. One would expect your software to be signed with certificate, issued by the authorized Certificae Authority.

Comment: Android requires signed code but explicitly accepts self-signed certificates: `You can use self-signed certificates to sign your applications. No certificate authority is needed.` ([Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html))

Comment: @Heinzi If you are asking about Android, please specify this in tags. Android is a special case - contents of the certificate don't matter at all and what is important is that the certificate is valid for 25 years and that the key remains the same. Android infrastructure uses the signature as proof of authorship but doesn't care about the name.

Comment: Does it really make a difference? Don't I have to choose a DN as well when I have a CA-signed certificate?

Comment: @Heinzi CAs usually have their own rules on filling certificate subject names.

Comment: I see. And is there a well-established convention (among the various CAs) on where the company name should go, if there is no "personal name" in the DN?

Comment: @Heinzi I don't know of such, and X.50* standards are also mute on this topic.